# Ignite Persistence not working in Yarn offline deployment

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Am trying to enable Ignite Native Persistence in Ignite Yarn Deployment. 
Purpose of this is to have data written to disc when RAM overflows.

But when I try to add large number of records to Ignite Grid, the node is getting disconnected and getting below exception.

```
Error :class org.apache.ignite.internal.NodeStoppingException: Operation has been cancelled (node is stopping). 
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.NodeStoppingException: Operation has been cancelled (node is stopping). 
 ERROR com.project$$anonfun$startWritingToGrid$1: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1287) 
 ERROR com.project$$anonfun$startWritingToGrid$1: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1648) 
 ERROR com.project$$anonfun$startWritingToGrid$1: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.putAll(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1071) 
 ERROR com.project$$anonfun$startWritingToGrid$1: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.putAll(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:928)
```

Please find below the details.

Ignite Version : 2.3.0

Cluster details for Yarn Deployment:

```
IGNITE_NODE_COUNT=10 
IGNITE_RUN_CPU_PER_NODE=5 
IGNITE_MEMORY_PER_NODE=10096 
IGNITE_VERSION=2.3.0 
IGNITE_PATH=/tmp/ignite/2.3.0/apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin.zip 
IGNITE_RELEASES_DIR=/tmp/ignite/2.3.0/releases 
IGNITE_WORKING_DIR=/tmp/ignite/2.3.0/work 
IGNITE_XML_CONFIG=/tmp/ignite/2.3.0/config/ignite-config.xml 
IGNITE_USERS_LIBS=/tmp/ignite/2.3.0/libs 
IGNITE_LOCAL_WORK_DIR=/local/home/ignite/2.3.0
```

Ignite Configuration for Yarn deployment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
           xsi:schemaLocation=" 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd"> 
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration"> 
                <property name="clientMode" value="false"/> 
                 <property name="dataStorageConfiguration"> 
                    <bean 
class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration"> 
                      <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration"> 
                       <bean 
class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration"> 
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/> 
                        </bean> 
                      </property> 
                    </bean> 
                </property> 
                <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/> 
                <property name="networkTimeout" value="10000000"/> 
                <property name="networkSendRetryCount" value="50"/> 
                <property name="discoverySpi"> 
            <bean 
class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi"> 
                <property name="ipFinder"> 
                    <bean 
class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder"> 
                        <property name="addresses"> 
                          <list> 
                                     <value><hosts>:47500</value>                 
                            </list> 
                        </property> 
                    </bean> 
                </property> 
                                <property name="networkTimeout" 
value="10000000"/> 
                                <property name="joinTimeout" 
value="10000000"/> 
                                <property name="maxAckTimeout" 
value="10000000"/> 
                                <property name="reconnectCount" value="50"/> 
                                <property name="socketTimeout" value="10000000"/> 
            </bean> 
        </property> 
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Code to Add Data to grid :

```
var cacheConf: CacheConfiguration[Long, Data] = new
CacheConfiguration[Long, Data]("DataCache")
    cacheConf.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
    cacheConf.setIndexedTypes(classOf[Long], classOf[Data])
val cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConf)
var dataMap = getDataMap()
cache.putAll(dataMap)
```

Code to Count records:

```
val sql1 = "select * from DataCache"
val count = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(sql1)).getAll.size()
```

Comment: When native persistence is enabled, then eviction is not applied. And I don't see eviction policy in your config. The issue should be somewhere else. Please attach code, that you use to load data and calculate the number of the entries in cache. Maybe there is just a collision by keys?

Comment: Thanks for the Comment Denis. The count mismatch issue is resolved after changing the key generation logic. Now getting an exception when loading more data. Edited the above post with the Exception and the code to access Ignite grids.

Comment: Well, the node is stopping for some reason. Do you call Ignite.close() anywhere or create Ignite instance in try-with-resources block? Do you see other exceptions in logs?

Comment: Ignite.close() is called at the end of execution in finally block. But this exception tracks back to cache.putAll method. Ignite instance is not created in try-with-resources block. Sometimes getting this exception : Error :class org.apache.ignite.IgniteClientDisconnectedException: Failed to send custom message: client is disconnected.

Comment: Do your nodes stop, if you remove all calls to ignite.close() methods? If so, YARN must be affecting the node's lifecycle.